# Binding this to original object in higher-order function

Tags: javascript, this

In JavaScript, is it possible to bind the `this` object to a function returned by a higher-order function? The code sample below is essentially what I am using:

```
var restrict = function(restrictOn, fn) {
   var that = this;

   return function() {
      if (arguments[0] === restrictOn) {
         throw new Error("Condition not met");
      }

      return fn.apply(/*original object*/that, arguments);
   };
};

var MyConstr = function(name) {
   this.name = name;
};
MyConstr.prototype.sayNameWhenNotThree = restrict(3, function() {
   return this.name;
});

var myObj = new MyConstr("Fido");
myObj.sayNameWhenNotThree(3); // Throws error - OK
myObj.sayNameWhenNotThree(5); // SHOULD return "Fido" - does not
```

In this example, the `restrict()` function correctly passes through to the function that it is wrapping, but it is not executing in the context of the `myObj` function. I have tried various `this` bindings in the `apply` call, but I cannot figure out how to retain the binding to the original object. Can this be done cleanly?

Comment: Have you tried using `this` from within the returned function, ie directly inside `fn.apply(this, arguments);`?  I believe at that point it should be referring to the correct object?

Comment: Hah! I think that's the only think that I _hadn't_ tried, but it works! I'll accept this if you write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` within your inner function:

```
var restrict = function(restrictOn, fn) {
   /* at this point this refers to whatever context restrict 
   is called in, in this case - it's window */

   return function() {
      if (arguments[0] === restrictOn) {
         throw new Error("Condition not met");
      }
      /* at this point this refers to the proper target that the returned
      function is being assigned to */
      return fn.apply(this, arguments);
   };
};
```